# Except for non gmail addresses, how do i make gmail addresses to be strictly ending with '@gmail.com' (and not something as '@gmail.com.au', etc)

Tags: python, django

How to validate an email address in a form to be only as 'gmail.com' but raise an error if the domain name and extension is anything other than 'gmail.com'? 
I get an error if the email address ends with @gmail.au.com for example

```
from django import forms
from .models import User

class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'country']


    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email_base, provider = email.split('@')
        domain, extension = provider.split('.')
        if domain == 'gmail' and extension != 'com':
            raise forms.ValidationError('Please enter a valid gmail address.')
        return email
```

Comment: I'm guessing the error is to do with too many values to unpack? If I understand correctly, why can't you do `if provider != 'gmail.com':` and ignore the `split('.')`?

Comment: yes you are right @roganjosh. but i want other providers as well. Its only when it comes to gmail address it needs to be only 'gmail.com'

Comment: By all means, use [`email.utils.parseaddr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parseaddr) and check if the second element of the tuple ends in `gmail.com`.

Comment: Wait, what? "but raise an error if the domain name and extension is anything other than 'gmail.com'" and "but i want other providers as well". The function returns `email` immediately afterwards, nothing else. Your goal is now unclear.

Comment: thanks for replying. I want non gmail addresses to be registered through django default email validation. but only if someone adds a gmail address, it should be strictly ending with '@gmail.com' (and not something as '@gmail.com.au' or @gmail.au.com, etc)

Comment: Then you need to edit your question to actually reflect what it is you're trying to do because your last comment is miles away from what you're asking in the question.

Comment: Sorry i wasnt able to put it correctly the first time

Answer (score 4):

You can just check whether or not the email includes `@gmail` and ends with `@gmail.com`, theres no need to split it at all

```
if '@gmail' in email and not email.endswith('@gmail.com'):
```

Comment: Based on comments, I think this question is about to change. Heads up :)

Comment: @roganjosh - If the question were to change then it should be rolled back, although my answer still applies to both the original and the clarified question

Comment: For the clarified question it would require an extra step because if the email doesn't contain 'gmail' anywhere, then it should not raise an error. It is only emails that contain 'gmail' that should undergo the extra validation. But OP only changed the title and not the text, so now it's in a strange middle ground

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve it. Below are the changes in your code which will make it run. Code further, explore, and let us know for issues :)

```
>>> provider = 'gmail.com.au'
>>> provider_list = provider.split('.')
>>> domain, extension = provider_list[0], ''.join(provider_list[1:])
```